# VB.NET using an activex exe programmed in VB6 (type mismatch)

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I created an active x exe in VB6 and tried to use it from within VB.NET.

All is working fine so far except that I don't know how to declare the variables.
The error I am getting is "Object of type int16 is not compatible with type of int32".

The function in the ActiveX exe is

```
Public Function GetMessages(ByRef uKeyCode() As Integer, ByRef uMouseButton() As Integer, ByRef uDown() As Boolean, ByRef uInjected() As Boolean, ByRef uExtraInfo() As String, ByRef uX() As Long, ByRef uY() As Long, ByRef uWheelDelta() As Long, ByRef uTime() As Long) As Long
```

I tried passing

```
Dim iKeyCodes() As Integer
```

to this function, also

```
Dim iKeyCodes() As Int16
```

But that did not work.

Can somebody tell me the correct declaration?

Comment: Or in other words, what are the equivalents to VB6-Integer and VB6-Long in .NET, please?

Comment: See [Data types in VB and .NET](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/datatypes.html) for a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are you conversions:

- The VB6-Integer is equivalent to the VB.NET `Short`, which holds signed 16-bit (2-byte) integers that range in value from -32,768 through 32,767.
- The VB6-Long is equivalent to the VB.NET `Integer`, which holds signed 32-bit (4-byte) integers that range in value from -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647.